# Direct open different link on start of the activity

Tags: android, android-applicationinfo

Is It Possible To open 2 url At a time from android app without opening the layout.
I can open these two in two different activity or using two button in same activity.

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("http://www.facebook.com");
        startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri));

Uri uri = Uri.parse("http://www.gmail.com");
        startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri));
```

Is it possible to open them from same activity directly as the application start??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK You can not open two links at the same time and view in activity.As you can have access to the single activity at a time in android, So browser is a kind of activity which you are requesting for opening url. You can not show two different links at a same time.

But yes its possible to open link directly at the start up of application.

Comment: hmm in start up i can able to open 1 link directly.. but what about two link. If It possible i can create shortcut for both the link and use later directly.. ?? Any idea?

Comment: How it is possible to open link directly at the start up of application??

Comment: Just call the url loading code using intent on your application's first screen onResume() method.

Comment: Hmm Than it will open 1 link what about other link ??

Comment: As i said you can open single link at a time. Not multiple.

Comment: hmm actually client requirement is that.. so m searching for possibilities. any way thanks a lot :)